# How to declare type 'HTMLButtonElement' into my interface in TSX React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to Ts, I'm making a custom component for the Popover in MUI, I'm passing trough props, the anchorEl and setAnchorElement in order to position my popover properly.

Based on the example of the documentation :

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=demo.tsx

`const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);`

As you can see this elements are type `<HTMLButtonElement>`

And this is my custom Component interface.

```
interface DialogProps {
  title?: string
  children: React.ReactNode
  isOpen: boolean
  setIsOpen(value: boolean): void
  anchorEl: any /* Html button element */
  setAnchorEl: any /* Html button element */
}
```

I want to remove the "any" type from `anchorEl` and `setAnchorEl` but I don't know how to declare this HTML type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `anchorEl` is the type you pass to `useState`, and the setter `useState` returns is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>`, so your interface should look like this:

```
interface DialogProps {
  title?: string
  children: React.ReactNode
  isOpen: boolean
  setIsOpen(value: boolean): void
  anchorEl: HTMLButtonElement | null;
  setAnchorEl: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HTMLButtonElement | null>>;
}
```